# Weird ContextMenuStrip style when used with NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am trying to create a notification area icon with a custom menu, and it works fine for the most part.

The problem is, the menu has a very strange style set to it - check the image. You need to click on this small box to activate the item, clicking on the area around it does nothing.

[image]

How can I change the style to the standard one where you can click on the entire button? Changing Renderer and RenderMode does not seem to help. This is the only notification icon on my system with this menu style.

```
            _trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            _trayMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();

            _trayIcon.Icon = Resources.trayicon;
            _trayIcon.Text = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            _trayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = _trayMenuStrip;
            _trayIcon.Visible = true;

            _trayMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripButton("&Configure...", null, OpenConfigManager));
            _trayMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
            _trayMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripButton("&Exit", null, (sender, args) => Application.Exit()));
```

Comment: Yes, that's what a ToolStripButton looks like.  A very uncommon choice for a context menu.  Fall in the pit of success by using the designer.  If you want to do it in code then add ToolStripMenuItems instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant mentioned, I used ToolStripButtons instead of ToolStripMenuItems by mistake. After changing those everything looks fine.